# How to connect to snowflake using R in VScode?

Tags: r, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm writing an R file that needs to call on multiple SQL queries I have in folder. Currently, I have the snowflake extension in vs code. Because I have the extension, should I automatically be able to call and run those SQL queries to load my data to perform EDA?

Thinking of something like this, but don't know what 'con' would be if I have the extension and use SSO.

```
historical_stats = as_tibble(dbGetQuery(con, read_file(here("sql", "historical_stats.sql"))))
```

The closest I have come to solving was this https://hevodata.com/learn/snowflake-r/ , but it assumes I'm using Rstudio and would need an OBDC driver. It also doesn't take into account SSO or roles in snowflake. Is what I'm trying even possible?

Comment: I think if you are going to call Snowflake from R within VSCode then the connector will not work because that is a live interactive thing from snowflake, you are basically running their worksheets feature remotely.  You should treat it like you would if you called snowflake from RStudio or R terminal, install the appropriate packages and use traditional login and password methods

Comment: @sconfluentus I guess that makes sense, I'll just have to do that then. Thanks!